# How do I show two object are adjacent to each other?

Tags: java

I have to read in a file that shows one letter (City) is adjacent to the other. They are separated by a tab.

How do I show that Q is adjacent to X, R is adjacent to X (also), P is adjacent to R, etc etc...?

```
Q   X
R   X
P   R
P   W
W   S
S   T
T   W
W   Y
Y   R
Y   Z
```

Segment of code to read in the file:

```
private ArrayList<City> cityList;
private ArrayList<City> cityFromList;
private ArrayList<City> cityToList;
Scanner theFlightFile = null;

    try {
        theFlightFile = new Scanner (new File("flightFile.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception FileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.println(FileNotFoundException.getMessage());
    }
    while (theFlightFile.hasNext()) {
        String cityFrom = theFlightFile.next();
        String cityTo = theFlightFile.next();
        City cityA = new City(cityFrom);
        City cityB = new City(cityTo);

        cityToList.add(cityA);
        cityFromList.add(cityB);
        //testing input reading...
        System.out.println(cityFrom + " -----> " + cityTo);
    }
```

Method to that displays the names of all the cities which are adjacent to 'aCity'. @param aCity The city for which the adjacency list is desired.

```
    //this is completely wrong, I know...
public void displayAdjacentCities(City aCity) {
    //for (aCity  : cityFromList) {
    //  for (City cityB : cityToList) {
    //      System.out.println(cityA + " is adjacent to " + cityB);
    //  }
    //}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you will need an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I havent learned anything about that yet. Don't know if I am allowed to use it.

Comment: are you learning about programming? Do you know about `List`, `Set` and `Map` interface? Do you know about arrays and array of arrays (commonly known as matrix)? Then you know the basics to create an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know those interfaces and matrix. I mean I'll definitely look into, but I dont know I am allowed to use something that we haven't learned yet. My teacher is anal like that.

Comment: Well, you just read the concept and learn to implement one. Will your teacher be mad about you learning something by yourself?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza she better not be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashMap<City, HashSet<City>>` structure where the key is a city object and it points to a set of its adjacent cities.

Comment: You mean `Map<City, List<City>>` backed by `LinkedHashMap<City, List<City>>`. Also, it will be worth to mention that `City` class must override `equals` and `hashcode` methods in order to make this approach to work.

Comment: Better `HashMap<City,HashSet<City>>` ... It would be faster to test.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you mention trivial things to use that, because I mention a map implementation and the OP is supposed to know that already.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk a better option would even be `Set<City>` where `City` contains a `Set<City> adjacentCities`.

Comment: @Juvanis maybe not, we don't know for sure if OP knows about `Set` (at least not before the comment on question).

Comment: One more thing, it would be better for you to check this link: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < cityFromList.length(); i++) {
  if (cityFromList.get(i).equals(aCity)) {
    System.out.println(aCity + " is adjacent to " + cityToList.get(i) + ".");
  }
}
```

This of course requires that the "City" class would need to implement the equals method and hence the hashcode method as well.

Comment: I have a City class, but didnt include it. I didn't think it would be relevant to what I have